# How can i increase the distance between specific xticks in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a timeline with years, and eventually have a forecasted amount which includes year 2050 and 2100. Currently when i plot it, it will come out as such:[image]

So there is equal distance from 2012 to 2050, it treats it as if it were another 2 index forward. My xticks print out as follows:

[  0.   2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.]

and my xticklabels are:

[2000, 2002, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2050]

So its behaving exactly as it is supposed to, but how do i make it realize that there is a wider gap between 2012 & 2050 than there is between 2010 & 2012? Ive tried assigning the year column as xticks but that wouldn't work and the output would look something like:

[image]

How im currently doing the xticklabels:

```
xlabelvals = []
for i in range(len(valsx)-1):
    xlabelvals.append(plotDf.Year[int(valsx[i])])

ax.set_xticklabels(xlabelvals)
ax.set_xticks(xlabelvals,xlabelvals)  #returns a messed up plot
```

Answer (score 0):

So, from the matplotlib function xticks, matplotlib.pyplot.xticks(..) 
You have:

> # set the locations and labels of the xticks   xticks( arange(5),
>   ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue') )

So if you want it on exact scale, you can just setup X twice, else, if you want just a slight increase in distance, you can set it up as wanted, with an equal sized array as the first argument, hope it helps. image bellow for example.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm using pandas and I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate what you just said to my code. I can't do ax.xticks(x,x) because it returns the same weird graph which i have up top. I pasted some of my code above.